# VueJS - Scoped slots and manipulation of data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vuejs component `edit-form` with a named slot `body` inside of it and data called `model`.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <pre>{{ model }}</pre>
        Name: <input v-model="model.name"><br>
        <slot name="body" v-bind="model"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            model: {
                name: "x",
                title: "y"
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I am using this component in a parent component like so:

```html
  <edit-form>
    <template v-slot:body="model">
      Title: <input v-model="model.title">
    </template>
  </edit-form>
```

When I now enter something in the `name` input field, then the `<pre>{{ model }}</pre>` tag gets updated. Modifying the `title` input field has no effect on the `<pre>`.

See https://codepen.io/bernhardh/pen/KKwEVZo

How to make the `title` input field work?

Comment: It seems that Vue only passes the **copy** (plain object) of the reactive object when bound to a component as a slot prop. So in this case, I'd agree with Sherzodbek that you'd probably need to pass these as the component `props` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do in this code some changes! For example

Html code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <edit-form v-model="model">
    <template slot="body">
      Title: <input v-model="model.title">
    </template>
  </edit-form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Vuejs code:

```
Vue.component('edit-form', {
      template : `<div>
              <pre>{{ value }}</pre>
              Name: <input v-model="value.name"><br>
              <slot name="body"></slot>
            </div>`,
     props:{
       value: {
         reqired: false,
         type: Object
       }
     },
    data: function() {
      return {

      };
    }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: '#container',
    data: {
      value: '',
      model: {
          name: "x",
          title: "y"
        }
    },
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I want to achive. The model data is in the `edit-form` component, not in the parent. Btw. `slot="body"` is the deprecated form. You should use `v-slot:body`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax

Comment: Actually I can't find a better solution, so I have to do it like you suggested

Comment: You need to read the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) better and understand the philosophy of [vue.js](https://vuejs.or).